# PHP Soap Header with SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, header

I am zero experienced with the SOAP client.
So far I can retrieve a list of publications, but I supposed to set a header.

The XML format looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Export" nillable="true" type="Export" />
  <xs:complexType name="Export">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Header" type="GenericHeader" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Publications" type="ArrayOfGenericObject" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="GenericHeader">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Action" type="EAction" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserReference" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="EAction">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="RESET" />
      <xs:enumeration value="UPDATE" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
.......... etc
```

How do I supposed to set the Export EAction to RESET?

So far I have this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://weblink.xxxxxxxxx.com/weblink.asmx?wsdl", array(
  'login'     => "xxxxxxx",
  'password'  => "xxxxxxx",
));
$result = $client->GetPublicationSummaries();
```